# Random Avatar plugin for Joomla/JomSocial - How to diagnose and fix?

Tags: php, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, jomsocial

I'm pretty new at this but I want to learn...

I have a GPL plugin (for Joomla 1.6 / JomSocial 2.6) that I would like to use (w/ Joomla 2.5 & JomSocial 2.8) but it will need some fixing or updating. It should check for a default avatar and replace it with a random one. It installed but doesn't work.

1. How can I verify it's getting the data it needs?
2. I think one problem might be no file listed in the database is default. It looks like this plugin expects one to be there.

   ```
   function onUserLogin($user, $options)
   {
       $juser = CFactory::getUser($user);
       $curavatar = $juser->getThumbAvatar();

       $gender = $juser->getInfo($this->params->get( 'genderfield' , 'FIELD_GENDER' ));

       if($this->compareEnd("default.jpg", $curavatar) || $this->compareEnd("user.png", $curavatar) || ($this->contains('minisocialgender_images',$curavatar) && $this->params->get( 'reassign' , '0' )))
       {
   ```

The script is only about 100 lines so I hope someone can point out some obvious problems.

Thanks for looking and any help you can offer. Here's the rest of the script...

```
// no direct access

defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

jimport( 'joomla.plugin.plugin' );

require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'components' . DS . 'com_community' . DS . 'libraries' . DS . 'core.php');

class plgUserMiniSocialGender extends JPlugin
{

function plgUserMiniSocialGender(& $subject, $config)
{
    parent::__construct($subject, $config);
}

//function onLoginUser($user, $options)
function onUserLogin($user, $options)
{
    //$juser = $this->getJomSocialUser($user);
    $juser = CFactory::getUser($userid);

    //$curavatar = $juser->getAvatar();
    $curavatar = $juser->getThumbAvatar();

    $gender = $juser->getInfo($this->params->get( 'genderfield' , 'FIELD_GENDER' ));
    //$gender = $user->getInfo('FIELD_GENDER');

    if($this->compareEnd("default.jpg", $curavatar) || $this->compareEnd("user.png", $curavatar) || ($this->contains('minisocialgender_images',$curavatar) && $this->params->get( 'reassign' , '0' )))
    {
        if($gender)
        {
            $maleurl = JPATH_SITE . DS . 'plugins' . DS . 'user' . DS . 'minisocialgender' .DS . 'minisocialgender_images' . DS . 'male' . DS;
            $femaleurl = JPATH_SITE . DS . 'plugins' . DS . 'user' . DS . 'minisocialgender' .DS . 'minisocialgender_images' . DS . 'female' . DS;

            $usermodel =& CFactory::getModel('user');

            if($this->params->get( 'maletype' , 'Male' ) == $gender)
            {
                if($this->contains("male", $curavatar))
                    return;
            }

            if($this->params->get( 'femaletype' , 'Female' ) == $gender)
            {
                if($this->contains("female", $curavatar))
                    return;
            }

            if($gender == $this->params->get( 'maletype' , 'Male' ))
            {
                $files = $this->getDirItems($maleurl);
                $random =   rand ( 0 , (count( $files) - 1));

                JFile::copy($maleurl . $files[$random], JPATH_SITE . DS . 'plugins' . DS . 'user' . DS .'minisocialgender' .DS . 'minisocialgender_images' . DS . $juser->id . 'male' . '.png');
                JFile::copy($maleurl . 'thumb' . DS .$files[$random], JPATH_SITE . DS . 'plugins' . DS . 'user' . DS . 'minisocialgender' .DS . 'minisocialgender_images' . DS . 'thumb' . $juser->id . 'male' . '.png');

                $usermodel->setImage($juser->id, 'plugins' . DS . 'user' . DS . 'minisocialgender' .DS . 'minisocialgender_images' . DS . $juser->id . 'male' . '.png', 'avatar');
                $usermodel->setImage($juser->id, 'plugins' . DS . 'user' . DS . 'minisocialgender' .DS . 'minisocialgender_images' . DS . 'thumb'  . $juser->id . 'male' . '.png', 'thumb');
            }
            elseif($gender == $this->params->get( 'femaletype' , 'Female' ))
            {
                $files = $this->getDirItems($femaleurl);
                $random= rand ( 0 , (count( $files) - 1) );

                JFile::copy($femaleurl . $files[$random], JPATH_SITE . DS . 'plugins' . DS . 'user' . DS . 'minisocialgender' .DS . 'minisocialgender_images' . DS . $juser->id . 'female' . '.png');
                JFile::copy($femaleurl . 'thumb' . DS . $files[$random], JPATH_SITE . DS . 'plugins' . DS . 'minisocialgender' .DS . 'user' . DS . 'minisocialgender_images' . DS . 'thumb' . $juser->id . 'female' . '.png');

                $usermodel->setImage($juser->id,  'plugins' . DS . 'user' . DS . 'minisocialgender' .DS . 'minisocialgender_images' . DS . $juser->id . 'female' . '.png', 'avatar');
                $usermodel->setImage($juser->id,  'plugins' . DS . 'user' . DS . 'minisocialgender' .DS . 'minisocialgender_images' . DS . 'thumb' . $juser->id . 'female' . '.png', 'thumb');
            }

            if($this->params->get( 'warnuser' , 1 ))
            {
                JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage( $this->params->get( 'warnmessage' ));
            }
        }
    }
}

function getDirItems($dir)
{
    $files = array();
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                if(filetype($dir . $file) == "file")
                {
                    $files[] = $file;
                }
            }
            closedir($dh);
        }
    }
    return $files;
}

function compareEnd($end, $fullstring)
{
    $StrLen = strlen($end);
    $FullStrEnd = substr($fullstring, strlen($fullstring) - $StrLen);
    return ($end == $FullStrEnd);
}

function contains($needle, $haystack)
{
    $pos = strpos($haystack,$needle);
    if($pos)
    return true;
    else
    return false;
}

//function getJomSocialUser($user)
//{
//  $user2 =& JFactory::getUser();
//  $userid = $user2->id;
//  return CFactory::getUser($userid);
//}
}
```